# Exiting pyomo solve: Multiple models defined in file 'cw.py'

Tags: python, error-handling, abstract, prompt, pyomo

I'm very new to pyomo and i'm trying to solve my coursework in a lesson of my master.
In Spyder the model works fine but in prompt shows the following:

```
[    0.33] Creating model


[    0.34] Pyomo Finished
Exiting pyomo solve: Multiple models defined in file 'cw.py'!
```

errorcode: "Multiple models defined in file 'cw.py'!"
retval: None

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Please try to provide more information - if we do not have access to your `cw.py` file, the only thing we can tell you is to please do not define multiple models in a single file...

Comment: i used the following in the spyder

"" instance = model.create_instance('WasteDisposal.dat')
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
solver.solve(instance)
instance.pprint()
instance.display() ""

Should i delete them in order to run the code in the prompt?
Maybe these are the multiple models?

Is this helpful?
I'm really sorry but i do not know many things, i'm still an amateur !